# Keep a rolling average of a GPA without a div/0 error

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially I am saying, start with the average of all 4 semesters, if Sem 4 average is "0" or has a #div/0 error then just take sem 1-3 averages, if Sem 3 avg is 0 or #div/0 then just take sem 1-2 average, etc.

I have got it to a point where I get the error message "unable to get the average property for the worksheet function class."

---

```
Sub sem1avg()
    If w = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1") = "N/A"
    ElseIf w > 0 Then
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Average (Range("B2:B10"))
    End If
End Sub

Sub sem2avg()
    If x = 0 Then
        Call sem1avg
    ElseIf x > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range.cell(H1) = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(B11, B23)
    End If
End Sub

Sub sem3avg()
    If y = 0 Then
       Call sem2avg
    ElseIf y > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(H1) = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(B11, B23, E11)
    End If
End Sub

Sub sem4avg()
    Dim w As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim z As Long

    w = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B11")
    x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B23")
    y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E11")
    z = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E23")

    If z = 0 Then
        Call sem3avg
    ElseIf z > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1") = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.Average("B11, B23, E11, E23")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, a lot going on here. Good first effort. If you're going to call other subs, you need to pass arguments. `If y = 0 Then` is not going to work if you don't pass it. I let you research how to pass arguments ^_^

Comment: does this have to be done in vba?  Could you just use `=averageif` function?

Comment: You seem to be confused about how to use ranges in the code. you cannot just type the address of the range in the code. The correct way to do it is the one used in `sem4avg` (`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B11")`)

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(H1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate ("Average(B11, B23, E11)")` Another way in lieu of @litelite statment.

Comment: Wow, Thank you for all of your help. I really appreciate the quick and solid feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could just use the AGGREGATE() Function:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,B11,E11,B23,E23)
```

The AGGREGATE() Function was introduced in 2010 to deal with this specific problem.  The first criteria tells the function we want the average, the second tells the formula to exclude errors.  The third is the range.

[image: ![enter image description here]

To deal with the `0` and the Errors this formula will do it:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B11),B11),IF(ISNUMBER(B23),B23),IF(ISNUMBER(E11),E11),IF(ISNUMBER(E23),E23))/SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B11),IF(B11>0,1)),IF(ISNUMBER(B23),IF(B23>0,1)),IF(ISNUMBER(E11),IF(E11>0,1)),IF(ISNUMBER(E23),IF(E23>0,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This neglects OP's requirement for testing `z`? Or, in another words, how does this compare with `averageif`?

Comment: Oh and AverageIf () will not work due to the possible errors.

Comment: My first question is null now that I understand `aggregate` more. So there's really no use for `averageif`.

Comment: @findwindow it is still the fastest method when the data is consecutive and free of errors.  It is a non array formula and therefore can use full column and row references, but it is limited.

Comment: @findwindow see edit as I have found an array formula that ignores both the `0` and errors.

Comment: Too lazy to study it =P Just wanted to troll you into doing extra work.  /hides

Comment: Ok, I don't get why some formulas are array and some are not.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one thing happening and so far no one has hit all of it.

You need to pass your arguments.

You need to use the 'Average' function correctly

You also need to change your variables to Single, Long is going to round up or down which will really mess up your results.

Here's a sample of how to fix it:

```
Sub sem3avg(ByVal w As Single, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
If y = 0 Then
   Call sem2avg
ElseIf y > 0 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(w, x, y)
End If


End Sub

Sub sem4avg()
Dim w As Single
Dim x As Single
Dim y As Single
Dim z As Single

w = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B11")
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B23")
y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E11")
z = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E23")


If z = 0 Then
Call sem3avg(w, x, y)
ElseIf z > 0 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(w, x, y, z)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `no one has hit all of it` because rarely do people learn when confronted with so much especially a beginner. Also, if you're going to provide turnkey, `Call sem2avg` is left hanging.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be cocky and didn't want to provide a turnkey. I left sem2avg and sem1avg out of it so he could figure those two out himself.

Comment: @phil, Why do I need to use "byval" is I have already used DIM to assign those variables?

Comment: @cdipaola Way late, but DIM establishes the variables inside of sub sem4avg() only. Sem3avg() cannot access those variables. So you use byval to pass the value of those variables to sem3avg() and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The function `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average` does not work like that. Instead, you need to pass it a bunch of number like so :

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(w,x,y,z)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836809.aspx